# How does CakePHP's Translate Behavior determine which locale to use?

Tags: cakephp, translate, cakephp-2.3

I thought CakePHP's Translate behavior used the following to determine what to query against in the i18n table:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'en');
```

But even with this, on one page it queries against `locale='en'` and on another, it uses `locale='eng'`.

I've verified that it IS being set to 'en' on both pages - so... why is it querying with 'eng' on one page?

I would have though maybe it was getting set differently somewhere, but - I don't believe you can re-set a constant.

Comment: Did you use `$this->Model->locale` to set the locale?

Comment: @Fuhrmann - No, I'm not setting locale manually.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the following 2 links:
[Link 1](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.3/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L482), [Link 2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.3/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L216)